# For loop inside waypoints - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display a route with waypoints for a trip. I save all the coordinates to a MySQL varchar attribute and then pull it out with php and slice it up into an array so the two array elements fruits[0] and fruits[1] represent the start, the fruits[2] and fruits[3] represent the first waypoint, that is the second place visited and so on.

I am trying to display the route of the trip and it works perfectly if I don't use waypoints, that is, if I don't populate the waypts array with all points except start and finish.

This is my code

```
 <style>
      #map-canvas {
        width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
          }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var fruits = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;

            for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i+=2) {
           //text += cars[i]; 
            }

          </script>

     <script>
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var dbk = new google.maps.LatLng(fruits[0], fruits[1]);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: dbk,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
}
 function calcRoute() {

    var waypts = [];

    for (var i = 2; i < fruits.length -2; i+=2) {
      waypts.push(new google.maps.LatLng(fruits[i], fruits[i+1])); 
    };

    var request = {
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(fruits[0], fruits[1]),
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(fruits[fruits.length-2],fruits[fruits.length-1] ),
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var route = response.routes[0];
        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
        summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
        // For each route, display summary information.
        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
          var routeSegment = i + 1;
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
        }
      } else {
        alert("directions response "+status);
      }
    });
  }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Directions Waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsWaypoint) for the waypoints.

```
var waypts = [];

for (var i = 2; i < fruits.length -2; i+=2) {
  waypts.push({
     location:new google.maps.LatLng(fruits[i], fruits[i+1]),
     stopover:true
  }); 
};
```

[Working example with single LatLng waypoint](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypointsC.html)